# How to make Python calendar show 3 letters instead of 2?

Tags: python-3.x, calendar

I have this code

```
import calendar

print(calendar.month(2020, 5))
print()
```

and it shows

```
May 2020
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
             1  2  3
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10
11 12 13 14 15 16 17
18 19 20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

What i want to know is how i can manage it to show Mon Tue Wen Thu Fri Sat Sun instead of 2 letters

Well i solved it by adding w=3 to code so now it looks like this

```
import calendar

print(calendar.month(2020, 5, w=3))
print()
```

and the result is

```
May 2020
Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun
                  1   2   3
  4   5   6   7   8   9  10
 11  12  13  14  15  16  17
 18  19  20  21  22  23  24
 25  26  27  28  29  30  31
```